# How to validate the height and weight from a form field when entered with lbs or ' and " symbols on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am relatively new to ruby and ruby on rails and I am trying to validate a form to ensure that the height and weight of a person is entered with numeric values but the fields can take the lbs after the number on the weight as in 150lbs and the height entered as in 5' 7", but avoid the person entering the values in words as in five feet seven inches.

I have been digging to see if I can find a gem that does that or a plugin but to no avail.

Any help will be appreciate it.

Comment: Why not have a drop-down of acceptable values? Everything from 3' to 8' should be sufficient.

Comment: It's hard to force users to enter something like `5' 7"`, so I agree with @tadman.

Comment: They'll also put in 3' 4 5/8" if you give them enough room to try, and probably 198cm or 1982mm.

Answer (score 0):

i belive that links is useful http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
after that you make a simple validation on model.

validates :weight, :numericality => true

Comment: Thank you for your help and I am trying your suggestion Rodrigo.